# soup.find can't locate HTML path and returns "None" but the path does exist. does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to web scrape some data from yahoo finance. specifically, I am looking for the ESG score of [individual firms](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB/sustainability?p=FB). this is my first time using BeautifulSoup and request, as well as looking at HTML code. could someone look at my code and see where I went wrong?

thank you in advance!

```
# libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interact

# check if we can still access website
try: 
    ESG_data = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB/sustainability?p=FB').text
    print ('succes')
except:
    print('Could not retrive')

# parse the url
soup = BeautifulSoup(ESG_data, 'html5lib')

  # look for object , not working now 
ESG_score = soup.find('div',{'class':'Fz(36px) Fw(600) D(ib) Mend(5px)'})
print(ESG_score)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add user-agent in headers.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interact
# check if we can still access website
try: 
    headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36 Edg/95.0.1020.30',
    }

    params = (
        ('p', 'FB'),
    )

    ESG_data = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB/sustainability', headers=headers, params=params).text
    print ('succes')
except:
    print('Could not retrive')

# parse the url
soup = BeautifulSoup(ESG_data, 'lxml')

  # look for object , not working now 
ESG_score = soup.find('div',{'class':'Fz(36px) Fw(600) D(ib) Mend(5px)'}).text
print(ESG_score)
```

Comment: hi Mohammed, that worked! can you tell me a bit why I had to add this or where I can read more info about this stuff.?

Comment: I knew this from my little experience. Many sites require User Agent to protect the site from attacks and scraping. Use this site, it will make it easier for you to make a requests. [Link](https://curlconverter.com/)